# how jvm run program

Tags: java, jvm

program 1:    when i write one simple class B  without creating object in my java program. how JVM allocates memory to class code which contain member fields and member function.

```
class B
{
     int a=10;
     public void print()
     {
         System.out.println("inside B class");
     }

}
```

program 2:And when i create the object of that class then how jvm allocate memory for object...see code below

```
class B
{
    int a=10;
    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println("inside B class");
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        B b=new B();
        b.print();

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "how"? We need to know what your knowledge level is in this topic to be able to answer this. There are about a dozen levels on which this could be answered. Answering all of them would take a whole book.

Answer (score 2):

There are three levels of allocation in this example:

- when the class is loaded (usually the first time it is referenced somewhere in your code), then memory for its structure, its code and it static fields is allocated.
- when an instance is created (`new B()`) then memory for the non-static fields and some metadata (object header) is allocated. This memory is on the heap.
- when a method is called, then memory from the stack is allocated for local variables inside that method.

Answer (score 2):

This site is very informative,so do take a look of it [Link](http://www.cubrid.org/blog/dev-platform/understanding-jvm-internals/) you'll be able to understand that how jvm run program